# How to make C-j and return behave like they did pre Emacs 24

Tags: key-bindings

`C-j` used to newline-and-indent, now it doesn't indent anymore, but `RET` does. Now since I upgraded to Emacs 24 they are swapped. Is there any way to revert this?

Comment: Related: [Completely disable all auto-indentation](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14297/115)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply bind the keys to the functions you want, by adding this code to your init file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") #'newline-and-indent)
(global-set-key (kbd "<return>") #'newline)
```

You might want a different function for `return`, depending on your desired behavior.

Comment: with this I cannot use C-x b anymore because pressing return instead of selecting the file, emacs adds a newline to the minibuffer