# Prevent emacs to indent when yanking into html buffer

Tags: indentation, yank

I have disabled `electric indent mode`, as specified [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14307/9216), but when yanking text, indenting is still performed.

I am yanking text into an html buffer, and I do not want any change whatsoever to be applied to the yanked text. I want it as-is, no indentation, no nothing.

How can I achieve this? I am running:

> GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9)  of
>   2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian

Comment: Does it happen in a session started with `emacs -q`? `electric-indent-mode` is for indentation as you type, afaik there is no indentation when yanking, by default.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What is the major-mode exactly?

Comment: Some popular Emacs configurations, i.e., `prelude`, have this feature enabled. Try to reproduce the problem in `emacs -Q`.